# Save List of Lists in a file

Tags: python, list, file, save

I want to know if there is a simple way to save list of lists in a file to import it later again like the same list of lists. No matter the size of it.

```
List_lists=[["a",1,2,3,4],["b",1,2,3,4],["c",1,2,3,4],.....]
```

Also i want to know is there is a way to throw a list with the first element in each list (in this case "a", "b"). Giving as a result:

```
first_column=[["a","b","c",......]
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: (1) See module "pickle". (2) You have to use a for-loop or a list comprehension to iterate through the inner lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the list into a CSV file using the numpy module in python. Please see sample code below.

### code:

```
import numpy as np

List_lists=[["a",1,2,3,4],["b",1,2,3,4],["c",1,2,3,4]]

# using the savetxt 
# from the numpy module
np.savetxt("list.csv", List_lists, delimiter =", ", fmt ='% s')
```

### output CSV file:

[image]

You can use list comprehension to iterate and obtain the first element of the list. Please sample code below

### code:

```
List_lists=[["a",1,2,3,4],["b",1,2,3,4],["c",1,2,3,4]]
res = [item[0] for item in List_lists]
res
```

### output:

[image]

### Reading the CSV file:

```
import csv

with open('list.csv', newline='') as f:
    read = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(read)

print(data)
```

### Output:

[image]

### References:

[Saving list to CSV file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-save-list-to-csv/)

[List comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-first-element-of-each-sublist/)

[Reading CSV file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thanks. And to read the file and get the same List_lists as the same list of lists how can i do?

Comment: I have edited my answer and attached the sample code for reading the CSV file and the reference I used. Hope it helps

Comment: It's better to include text as text. Your output is illegible as an image on mobile devices, but would be easy to read if it were [formatted as a code block or using code fences](/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `zip()` function, which joins lists together in their corresponding order.

```py
l1 = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4]
l3 = ['c', 1, 2, 3, 4]

# To access them through a for loop:
for a, b, c in zip(l1, l2, l3):
    # Do something
```

Note that using nested lists are fine as well.